# Why does my Hearthstone keep on crashing?

Tags: hearthstone, windows-10

This problem has been occurring over and over again recently. Whenever I attempt to start up Hearthstone, it keeps on crashing. There is no error message and I am unable to force close the program through the Task Manager. All that is left is a loading screen with a white hue and the words "Not Responding" next to the application's name.

After about 10 minutes, the program will suddenly close on its own. Despite repeated attempts to start it up, it continues to crash.

Can anyone tell me why this is so?

Comment: Do you have anything else running at the time? Does this happen after a fresh reboot? any memory/CPU hogs running at the same time?

Comment: Did you try to uninstall/install hearthstone? I got a similar problem. It was when i wanted to install a game with steam (steam create an area on your computer to store and install the game) and when i was running hearthstone in a same time.

Comment: Blizzard has errorlogs in their folders, maybe you have one logfile with an errorcode inside of your Hearthstone or Battlenet Log folder.

Comment: @TimS. I was running a google chrome tab on the side. I usually play whilst watching Game of Thrones or the like. Could this be a RAM problem? But I did the same thing just a few days ago and I did not come across this problem.

Comment: You could try adding hearthstone.exe as an exception to Windows Defender.  The Windows 10 edition of Defender has been a culprit for Hearthstone performance issues

Comment: Hearthstone is written with Unity and as a result, there is a crash log file generated that should display the exception that is occurring.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running a Dell XPS L502X which comes with a integrated HD Graphic 3000 and a NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M Graphic card.   That issue was happening to me for the longest time till I went under my NVIDIA graphic settings and changed Hearthstone to run the HD Graphic 3000 and not the NVIDIA card.  Even though the NVIDIA is better at graphics, there must be something that in incompatible, because once I switch it, my Hearthstone run well.